# linecap property in highchart doesn't work

Tags: highcharts

Is there any example of linecap in highcharts. http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.line.linecap

I want to change it from round to butt. but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you can use square and effect should be the same

```
plotOptions:{
            line:{
                linecap: 'square',
                lineWidth:10,
                marker:{
                    enabled:false
                }
            }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9XSxD/